# Android app connect with Windows app on my desktop

Tags: android, wpf, windows

I am trying to develop a Windows Desktop app similar to Task Manager which can monitor my PC with Visual Studio Express. Now I want to develop one app for my Android phone with which I can connect to this Windows App from anywhere and see some of the graphs and little info (light weight) on my phone in a secure way.

What tools do I need on my desktop and Android phone to develop the app. How can I develop and connect it?  If you can help me it will be great.

Thanks.

Comment: developer.android.com has everything you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I have no idea about Android development. So I have asked here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easier way for you to do this is to create a server application which both your apps connect to which will need to be on the internet or on a network where both have access to it. The desktop app would be sending its' information and the phone application would be requesting that information. As for what the server needs to be, that is agnostic, however using REST or Websockets (More ideal but a bit harder to work with) for communication would probably be ideal.

To get started I would suggest looking up a tutorial where you do API requests to a server (On either Android or Windows Store Apps). Then look at building your own server application to distribute your own API.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into REST and Websockets but I am developing it as hobby so I need my Windows app to interact with Android app and get the visuals from Windows.